# How to cycle over 3 types of values in array [android]

Tags: android

I want to know the algorithm to cycle through the sample array below in a order like color1 -> color3 -> color 2 when a button gets clicked each time.

int[] colorList = new int[]{color1, color2, color3};

Currently, Im trying to do it like the sample below but unable to do it. 
If possible would you give me a helping hand ? I cannot find a solution to transition in a order I desire. I would love to hear from you!

```
void updateIndicators(int position) {
      for (int i = 0; i < indicators.length; i++) {
          indicators[i].setBackgroundResource(
                  i == position ? R.drawable.indicator_selected : R.drawable.indicator_unselected
          );
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need a cycle here? If you have only 3 items, just hardcode those indeces.. It will be only 3 lines of code. There is no benefit in using a cycle here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
public int getNextPosition(int prevPosition){
    int maxPosition=2;
    return (prevPosition+maxPosition)%(maxPosition+1);
}
```

This returns 2 when input is 0

1 when input is 2

and 0 when input is 1

So colorList[0]->colorList[2]->colorList[1]

You can also add **another** function to return the color:

```
public int nextColor(int prevPosition){
    return colorList[getNextPosition(prevPosition)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare global variable on your activity class file like below :

```
int buttonclickcount=0;
```

In your clicklistener:

```
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonclickcount++;
            if(buttonclickcount%3==0)
            {
                //set color 1 from array
            }
            else if(buttonclickcount%3==1)
            {

                //set color 2 from array
            }
            else if(buttonclickcount%3==2)
            {

                //set color 3 from array
            }
        }
    });
```